# override/redefine a C-Function which has a section attribute

Tags: c, linker, attributes, clang

I have the case where I need to overwrite some C-Functions of an SDK we use. The SDK is compiled as a lib and the functions we need to override are marked with
`__attribute__((weak))`
This works as it should when linking.
We override those functions then later in our files with the wanted definition.

Background:
The reason is that the SDK is not working in a standalone way but always needs a special tool which generates some global objects which are needed in the init-functions of the SDK. And we wanted to get rid of the tool and thus need new init-functions which do not rely on the global objects but on passing the configuration via pointer. Those functions are added additionally and no SDK-functions are removed.

Also the SDK shall not be altered in a way you can't use it anymore with the tool. So it must support both features, with the smallest changes possible which will not break the API and add support for the new API by us without the tool.

So following up, if we now have a function which has already an attribute defined, which references to a section like
`void __attribute__((section(".text.random"))) Random_init(){}`
it is not possible to override Random_init.
I do not get errors like it was redefined or anything but undefined symbols while linking which refer to those global objects, which of course are not generated anymore and are only used by the function which shall be overriden. And this works for all other 20 init-functions only for this one it does not and the only difference is the attribute already there.

I tried adding it together:
`void __attribute__((weak, section(".text.random"))) Random_init()`

which also does not work.

I also tried to add the attribute to the redefinition, but this also does not help.
We cannot just erase the section-attribute since it needs to be there for all the entities using the tool.

The compiler we use is a clang based TI LTS1.3.1-compiler.

I would like to provide a minimal example but since this combination only works with the sdk-code beeing compiled to a lib first, I just cannot.

I just try to show it:
SDK-function which is compiled inside the lib, c-file "Random.c":

```
extern RandConfig gRandConfig[];
extern int32_t gRandConfigNum;

void __attribute__((weak, section(".text.random"))) Random_init()
{
    uint32_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < gRandConfigNum; i++) 
    {
        Random_setSpecial(i, 
                (void*)gRandConfig[i].baseAddr,
                gRandConfig[i].size,
                &gRandConfig[i].attrs
        );
    }
}
```

related Header-file, Random.h:

```
void Random_init();
```

The `gRandConfig` and `gRandSpecialConfig` are produced in code by the tool, which are then linked against the library and we don't want to use them anymore.

All the context where this shall happen is in C but the libs are used from C++-context.
So for example this is how the override would look like in our .cpp-files:

```
#include "Random.h"

extern "C"
{

void Random_init()
{

}
}
```

The result when linking:

```
 undefined            first referenced
  symbol                  in file
 ---------            ----------------
 gRandConfig          ../../../../sdk-build/sdk.lib<Random.obj>
 gRandConfigNum       ../../../../sdk-build/sdk.lib<Random.obj>
```

The included header by the sdk also has guards for __cplusplus. So it shouldn't be a language issue.

Also we issued the compiler to compile with -ffunction-sections which shall at least help to sort unneeded functions out later on. But anyway it does not. Even when the function gets never called by anyone.

A dirty solution would be to just add dummy-variables for this one, so it's satisfied and does not complain but as you can imagine, that would be a workaround which produces a lot of problems later on and also takes space where we need every Byte of space.

Could it be that an section-function-attribute prevents the function from being overriden? I did not find anything at the gnu-documantation which says that one cannot override a function with an attribute.

Comment: You tagged C++.  Where do you discuss the C++ language?  The C and C++ are distinct languages.  For example, C++ allows function and operating overloading, whereas C doesn't.  Update your tags.

Comment: Have you tried this syntax? `void __attribute__((section(".text.random"))) __attribute__((weak)) Random_init()`

Comment: @Armandas Yes I tried that too. But this had the same effect as putting both into one attribute-directive.